# How come "var" works without specifying the namespace?

Tags: c#, runtime, var

I have the following code:

```
 var dataExistsResult = await _service.CheckifExists(RequestDto);
 if (dataExistsResult != null && dataExistsResult.CountProperties() > 0)
    //do something
```

But if i specify "var" `PropertiesWithData dataExistsResult = await _service.CheckifExists(RequestDto);` it doesn't work since the namespace is not included in the file:

```
namespace Core.Common
{
    public class PropertiesWithData
    {
```

I need to set `using Core.Common;` for that to work. How come "var" is working when running the program? And how come it possible to access properties of "var" if it knows the type but `using Core.Common;`  is not in the file? eg: `dataExistsResult.CountProperties()` Is `Core.Common.PropertiesWithData` added at runtime? eg `Core.Common.PropertiesWithData dataExistsResult = await _service.CheckifExists(RequestDto);`

Comment: what do you mean by "var" PropertiesWithData dataExistsResult ?

Comment: no he means that with `var` it compiles and with `PropertiesWithData` it require right `using`

Comment: it is just compiler feature that compiler implies  variable type by RHS expression ... for this `using` is not required as compiler implies  exactly the type with namespace ... you can think about this that compiler will replace `var` with wherever RHS expression return ... so in your example it would be `Core.Common.PropertiesWithData` or even `global::Core.Common.PropertiesWithData`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces are part of the type name. So when your code refers to a type (by name), it must specify the namespace one way or another.

When using `var`, the type is not referred to by name, so no namespace is necessary. The compiler knows what type it is because the method declaration includes the type name (including namespace).